# Error in nomogram factor name(s) not in the design: model.type x time event x.df lambda pred.at

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am using the "smart" dataset from the package "hdnom". Below mentioned is my code. I get the following error. Please let me know where I am going wrong. I am unable to understand the error.

**Error in nomogram(fit, model.type = "aenet", x, time, event, x.df, lambda = lambda,  : 
  factor name(s) not in the design: model.type x time event x.df lambda pred.at**

```
data("smart")
summary(smart)
dim(smart)
x = as.matrix(smart[,-c(1,2)])
str(x)
time = smart$TEVENT
#time <- as.numeric(time)
event = smart$EVENT
library(survival)
y = Surv(time, event)
suppressMessages(library(doParallel))
registerDoParallel(detectCores())
aenetfit = fit_aenet(x, y, nfolds = 10, rule = "lambda.1se",
                       seed = c(5, 7), parallel = TRUE)
names(aenetfit)
fit = aenetfit$model_init
alpha = aenetfit$alpha_init
lambda = aenetfit$lambda_init
adapen = aenetfit$pen_factor
suppressMessages(library("rms"))
x.df = as.data.frame(x)
dd = datadist(x.df)
options(datadist = "dd")
nom = nomogram(fit, model.type = "aenet", x, time, event, x.df,lambda = lambda, pred.at = 365 * 2,funlabel = "2-Year Overall Survival Probability")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version `4.0` and `5.0` of `hdnom` the function `hdnom.nomogram` was available, as documented [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hdnom/versions/5.0/topics/hdnom.nomogram) and [here](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/suppl/2016/08/23/065524.DC1/065524-2.pdf). The syntax was:

```
nom <- hdnom.nomogram(fit, model.type = "aenet", x, time, event, x.df, 
       lambda = lambda, pred.at = 365 * 2,
       funlabel = "2-Year Overall Survival Probability")
```

In version `6.0` this function was replaced by `hdnom::as_nomogram`:

```
nom <- as_nomogram(aenetfit, x, time, event, pred.at = 365 * 2,
                   funlabel = "2-Year Overall Survival Probability")
plot(nom)
```

From the help of `rms::nomogram`: this function accepts as input (the `fit` argument) only regression models that were created with `rms`; in addition,  `model.type` and `lambda` are not valid arguments of this function.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights @MacroSandri. It worked.